# Sets Closed Under Algebraic Operations (or Not)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prof. Charles Pinter's [A Book of Abstract Algebra](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486474178.html) asks whether the following operations are closed under the `*` operator:

- a*b = sqrt(|ab|) on the of Rational Numbers

I saw on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) that sqrt(2) is not Rational.

So, based on that answer, it seems to me that rational numbers are not closed under the above `*` operation.

$$a*b = a * ln(b)\quad\hbox{on}\quad \{x \in R : x > 0\}$$

My understanding of the above is that `a` and `b` must be greater than 0.

Looking at this [natural log graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#/media/File:Log.svg), it seems to me that Real numbers are closed under this `*` operation.

Please comment on my reasoning and confirm/deny if my answers are correct.

Comment: Note that in MathJax you won't get a set by typing {, you need \{.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  For your second example, you need to take positive numbers $a,b$ and ask yourself: is $a\ln(b)$ always a **positive** real number?  Note that it is not enough to say, as you have done, that it is a real number.

If you look again at the graph of natural log, I feel sure that you will be able to answer this.

Comment: Ah. So if we let `a = 1`, and `b = < 1`, then, per the graph, we should get a negative number. So, as you showed me, this second property does not hold. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct.  Though best of all would be to choose a single specific value of $b$.

Comment: Thanks. For the first question, what does it mean to take the square root of a rational?

Comment: Your first answer is fine - the square root of a rational is sometimes rational, e.g., $\sqrt4=2$, but not always.